# Alert dropdown Label when option is selected using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, alerts

I have a table with td's as follows,

In this there are 3 dropdown's where depending on the first dropdown the 2nd and 3rd dropdown's get displayed

Example: when Option 1 or Option 2 is selected from Solutions dropdown, then dropdown with `projectslist` ID get displayed and when Option 3 is selected then dropdown with `projectlist` ID get displayed.

```
    <td>
        <select name="solutions" id="solutions" style="width:210px;">
            <option value="0" label="--- Select Solution ---" selected="selected">--- Select Solution ---</option>
            <option value="1" label="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2" label="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3" label="Option 3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td width="30px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span style="line-height: 1.5;" id="solution_description">Select appropriate monitoring solution.</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr height="80px;">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="50px;"><strong>Project: </strong>
    </td>
    <td id="projectslist">
        <select name="project" id="project" style="width:210px;">
            <option value="0" label="--- Select a Project ---" selected="selected">--- Select a Project ---</option>
            <option value="1" label="Project 1">Project 1</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td id="projectlist" style="display:none;">
        <select name="project" id="project" style="width:210px;">
            <option value="0" label="--- Select a Project ---" selected="selected">--- Select a Project ---</option>
            <option value="2" label="Project 2">Project 2</option>
            <option value="3" label="Project 3">Project 3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

Now, I need to get a alert Project Label when ever a Project is selected

ie, when ever Project 1 is selected, I need to alerted that `you have selected Project 1` and if Project 2 is selected, then I need to be alerted that `you have selected Project 2` and etc...

so can any help me on this using Jquery

Comment: Are you trying something? Did you make a search? There are tons of articles that explain how to make this simple task with javascript or jquery

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I'm tyring it but I didnt get any solution for the same. Can you please help me on this...

Comment: First of all, you have duplicated ids (`project` and `projectlist` at least are duplicated). With this HTML you will have a lot of conflicts and problems.

Comment: @kiranKumar You would love AnuglarJS. JQuery is great for DOM manipulation but when it comes to more advanced UI flow with data binding it is second to many client side frameworks. It is certainly worth the time learning AngularJS or BackboneJS for that matter.

Comment: @Guy he doesn't know how to develop with javascript. Do you think that he is ready to learn backbone and angular? Are you crazy xD

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, the requirement is like that... so you can't point it that I dont know how to develop with javascript... its worse on your part.

Comment: @Guy, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Sorry @KiranKumar, but if you don't know how to listen a simple change event, I can't consideer this that you know develop in javascript. What can you make with JS? What code are you trying with this issue? And how about duplicated ids? This demonstrates to me that you don't know how to develop with js. You can demonstrate me that I am mistaken sharing the code that you was tryed.

Comment: no problem @MarcosPérezGude

and here is my code 

`var el = document.getElementById('project');`
`project_name = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;`
`alert(project_name);`

with this I'm able to get the Label of Project 1 when selected Option1 and Option 2, but when I select Project 2 or Project 3, it return Project 1 instead of Project 2 or Project 3 from the example

Comment: @kiranKumar I built a version in AngularJS that shows the power of AngularJS (and client frameworks in general). Take a look if you'd like:
http://jsfiddle.net/858roLrt/1/

Comment: @KiranKumar please, read all comments. I tell you 20 minutes ago that you have duplicated ids.The result that you are receiving is because you have more than one `project` id. So when you make `document.getElementById("project")` you are selecting only the first occurrence. I still believe that you are not ready to learn backbone or angular.

Comment: @Guy, thanks for making it, but I need it in JQuery only.. cause my other has already been developed in JQuery itself

Comment: @Guy your efforts are very brave, but OP never ask angular solution. Please, read the help in stackoverflow to learn how to answer.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I know that I'm duplicating it bro... but I need to make it work with that... if you can able to make it please help.. else dont discourage in saying that I'm not ready to learn backbone... I already had used angular js in my mobile APP

Comment: You must to understand this: you **can't** use duplicated ids. Classnames, name attribute, data-*, type, and all attributes you want can be duplicated, but IDs no. If you want to continue with duplicated ids, you will have a lot of errors and conflicts that you will unable to fix. Tell me if you want to make a simple change, that is to change duplicated ids. `project1` and `project2` are valid ids.

Comment: I know. I just felt the comments can spare two lines for client framework missionarism ;-)

Comment: @guy I love angular (and I hate backbone. I used it in many projects. I'm with you that's better but this question seems to be closed due comprehensive reasons

Comment: He can solve the issue if he change duplicate ids. As simple as this

Comment: Solved the issue with out changing duplicate id's.... WOOOOO.. thanks guys for all your support

Answer (score 1):

Is as simple as listening change event. If you learn the first chapter of "Javascript for dummies" you achieve in 5 minutes.

With jQuery:

```
  $('#solutions').on('change', function(event) {
       alert("This is the value selected in solutions: " + $(this).val());
  });
```